# How can I multifilter redux state in react project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

This is my redux state :

```
    products: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Ps4',
            price: 4500000,
            number: 0,
            inCart: false,
            category: 'electronics',
            brand: 'sony',
            subCategory: 'game',
            img: 'ps4',
            stockNumber: 4,
            off: false,
            offPrice: null
        },
        {
            id: 24,
            name: 'Gucci',
            price: 7210000,
            number: 0,
            inCart: false,
            category: 'outfit',
            brand: 'gucci',
            subCategory: 'bag',
            img: 'gucci-bag',
            stockNumber: 2,
            off: false,
            offPrice: null
        },
        {
            id: 10,
name : 'Phone',
            price: 5800000,
            inCart: false,
            category: 'electronics',
            brand: 'samsung',
            subCategory: 'mobile',
            img: 'a70',
            stockNumber: 3,
            off: true,
            offPrice: 6000000
        }
]
```

And I loop through and display in component the way they are

```
    {props.products.map((item) => {
            return <div key={item.id}>{item.name}</div>
)}
```

Now I want to filter them by a multiple input checkboxes so when they're checked it filters them and displays only ones with stockNumber > 2 for example or multiple conditions and when it's unchecked it just gets the whole products .

```
<input onChange={()=>handleFilter('filter by stockNumber > 3')} />
<input onChange={()=>handleFilter('filter by inCart === false')} />
<input onChange={()=>handleFilter('filter by price > 200')} />
```

How can I achieve this and how many functions will make this work ?

Comment: What have you tried? Is there something specific that you're stuck on?

Comment: I've triend to filter() the whole array but it only happens once and when the input is unchecked it doesn't unfilter and I dont know how to combine multiple filters with checkboxes

Comment: You haven't shown us what `handleFilter` does, but regardless of it, I think you are missing the need to compose the filters but instead applying only the last one?

Comment: I dont know how to handleFilter I want to create it

Comment: It doesn't unfilter because you have probably already filtered the original `products` array and stored the result back in it.  Store the filtered array in different variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the logic a bit, in pseudo-js something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" onChange={toggleFilter1} />
<input type="checkbox" onChange={toggleFilter2} />
<input type="checkbox" onChange={toggleFilter3} />
```

```
  const filter1Enabled = input1Ref.checked // or state.input1Checked
  // ...

  const filteredProducts = props.products.filter(item => {
    if (filter1Enabled && doesntPass1(item)) return false
    if (filter2Enabled && doesntPass2(item)) return false
    if (filter3Enabled && doesntPass3(item)) return false
    return true
  })

  return (
    <>
      { filteredProducts.map(item => <div key={item.id}>{item.name}</div>) }
    </>
  )
```

So basically, you must keep track of which filters are enabled and then apply them in the filter one by one.